# How do you split an Array List into sublists everytime there is a duplicate value in the Array List

Tags: java, arrays

I have the following array list which contains the following
point ids (1,2,3,4,1,8,5,6,8,9,7,9). I am using Java 7

I was wondering how it could be split into sublists i.e the sublists below

(1,2,3,4,1)
(8,5,6,8)
(9,7,9)

I have had problems trying to use a loop within a loop (i.e check each point
from the outer loop with each of the other points in the inner loop) to get
index positions (starPosIndex and endPosIndex) where there are duplicate point ids and ArrayList.sublist(startPosIndex,endPosIndex) to get the correct sublist

```
int startPos = 0;
int endPos = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < polygonList3.size(); j++){
     Point pointToCheck = polygonList3.get(j);

     for (int k = 1; k < polygonList3.size(); k++){
         Point pointToCheck2 = polygonList3.get(k);
         if (pointToCheck.getID() == pointToCheck2.getID()){
             startPos = startPos + endPos;
            endPos = endPos + k;
             //startPos = startPos + endPos;
             //for (int startPos = j; startPos < polygonList3.size(); startPos = (startPos) + endPos) {
                 //endPos = Math.min(startPos + endPos, polygonList3.size());
                 finalPolygonLists.add(new ArrayList<Point>(polygonList3.subList(startPos, endPos)));//originalPtsSublist2);
             //}
         }
     }
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far

Comment: What kind of problems did you encounter using ArrayList.sublist?

Comment: Will the list always be composed of unique numbers bounded by duplictae numbers? I.E., what output would you want for (1, 2, 3, 2, 3) ?

Comment: The numbers will always be unique except for for where there are one pair of duplicate numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would solve it in the following manner:

1. Allocate a HashSet to contain unique values encountered
2. Allocate a new list for the first sublist
3. Iterate over the whole list, adding each value to the set. When we encounter a value that is already in the set, we are done with the first sublist, so clear the set, and allocate a new sublist
4. After iteration, you will have your list of sublists, obtained in O(n) runtime

Comment: Thanks James i'll give this a try. I had used LinkedHashSet in some of my other  methods where I needed to have unique values. I'll give this a try  .

Comment: @daveb With hashing you get the benefit of constant time `.contains`, which saves a lot of time compared to comparing each of the values to the other values according to your first attempt

Answer (score 1):

You can walk along the list, and create slices of the list (using `List#subList`) as you go. This can be done efficiently, by always checking whether the first element of the current segment of the list appears somewhere else in the list. If it does, you can store this "slice", and continue with the "tail" of the list. If it doesn't, you are finished (and the tail of the list may or may not be part of the result - that's up to you)

Implemented here as an example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class ListSlicing
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        runTest(1,2,3,4,1,8,5,6,8,9,7,9);
        runTest(1,2,3,4);
        runTest(1,1,1,1);
        runTest(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2);
        runTest();
    }

    private static void runTest(Integer ... numbers)
    {
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(numbers);
        System.out.println("Input:  "+list);
        System.out.println("Output: "+slices(list));
    }

    private static <T> List<List<T>> slices(List<T> input)
    {
        List<List<T>> slices = new ArrayList<List<T>>();
        List<T> current = input;
        while (current.size() > 0)
        {
            T first = current.get(0);
            int appearance = current.subList(1, current.size()).indexOf(first);
            if (appearance == -1)
            {
                slices.add(current);
                return slices;
            }
            List<T> slice = current.subList(0, appearance+2);
            slices.add(slice);
            current = current.subList(appearance+2, current.size());
        }
        return slices;
    }
}
```

The output is

```
Input:  [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 8, 5, 6, 8, 9, 7, 9]
Output: [[1, 2, 3, 4, 1], [8, 5, 6, 8], [9, 7, 9]]
Input:  [1, 2, 3, 4]
Output: [[1, 2, 3, 4]]
Input:  [1, 1, 1, 1]
Output: [[1, 1], [1, 1]]
Input:  [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]
Output: [[1, 2, 1], [2, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1], [2, 1, 2]]
Input:  []
Output: []
```

Comment: Thanks Marco13. Much appreciated. I am learning java so really appreciate you input

Answer (score 0):

The following code tracks the last position for each number and as soon as it founds a duplicate, it will create the sublist and clears all previously tracked entries.

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList( 1,2,3,4,1,8,5,6,8,9,7,9);

List<List<Integer>> sublists = new ArrayList<>();
Map<Integer,Integer> lastPos = new HashMap<>();

for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    Integer current = list.get(i);
    if(lastPos.containsKey(current)){
        sublists.add(list.subList(lastPos.get(current), i+1));
        lastPos.clear();
    } else {
        lastPos.put(current, i);
    }
}
System.out.println(sublists);
```

Comment: Thanks Gerald. Much appreciated